# Facebook API - retrieve users who listed a particular university in their education info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I want is to import into an alumni application all the Facebook users that publicly listed a certain university in their education info.
Does the Facebook API allow such a thing to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only search options are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

You can only search for users by name.